# Google won't index my site b/c of a 500 error, even though there's no server issue

Tags: wordpress, indexing, server, web-crawler

Any ideas why my website is returning 500 errors on nearly all my posts, despite the fact that there is no issue with the server? I've contacted GoDaddy and they assure me it is not an issue on their end. There's a post below as an example. Is it possible I've got a bad plugin or script somewhere that is causing this issue? I cannot figure it out for the life of me.

https://thedishmaster.com/2018/10/kenan-thompson-kanye-west-held-the-snl-cast-hostage.html

Comment: Check your error logs, that's the only way to know what's going on.

Comment: Error logs via google? I did, and it says it's a 500 error and that the link is "unreachable," but when you click on the link it works.

Comment: No, I meant your server error logs. Also, try enabling [WP's debug log](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Comment: Where would I find the server error logs? I enabled the debug feature on the SSL plugin.

Comment: Check here: https://uk.godaddy.com/help/working-with-error-logs-1197

Comment: [Wed Oct 03 10:47:46.020818 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 2718637:tid 139944476129024] [client 45.79.1.177:38644] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/r75t1kwy8f5w/public_html/wp-includes/css/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html.var,index.htm,index.html,index.xhtml,index.wml,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.js,index.jp,index.php4,index.php3,index.php,index.phtml,index.shtml,default.htm,default.html,home.htm,index.php5,Default.html,Default.htm,home.html,welcome.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

Comment: Here's what it says -- do you get it?

Comment: [Wed Oct 03 10:47:45.636997 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 2718426:tid 139944322369280] [client 45.79.1.177:38568] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/r75t1kwy8f5w/public_html/wp-includes/css/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html.var,index.htm,index.html,index.xhtml,index.wml,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.js,index.jp,index.php4,index.php3,index.php,index.phtml,index.shtml,default.htm,default.html,home.htm,index.php5,Default.html,Default.htm,home.html,welcome.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

Comment: That's telling you that there's no index.html/.php in `/wp-includes/css/`. Not sure that's what''s causing the error 500 Google sees. Is that everything? Please paste the entire log on pastebin.org and add it to your question.

Comment: *Site error detected.: https://thedishmaster.com/2018/10/kenan-thompson-kanye-west-held-the-snl-cast-hostage.html/

I also got this message from Godaddy: Internal Server Error

Details: http://labs.sucuri.net/db/malware/warning.500_internal_error?1

Comment: From Sucuri: "This error happens when your site generates a 500/501/503 internal server error when we try to scan it. It might be a temporary error, but it can also be related to a malicious injection gone wrong and breaking the site. If you get this warning, try to run a real time scan here: http://sitecheck.sucuri.net to see if the problem remains."